# How to update a string when contents of an IList<> are updated in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have an IList which is populated using the objects of the following class:

```
public class MenuCheckboxData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

This is the IList

```
public IList<MenuCheckboxData> MenuOptions
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = new List<MenuCheckboxData>();
```

This IList is updated via a CheckBoxList from the View and gets updated as per the changes made to the view at runtime which is fine.
Now there is another string in the same class:

```
string strFinalOpts="";
```

I want the strFinalOpts to be containing the Id of all the IList elements(separated by commas) where Checked=true.

How to get the strFinalOpts updated when the Checked property of any object in the IList is updated/changed from the View?

Comment: You could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `MenuCheckboxData` and subscribe to `PropertyChanged` events of each item.

Comment: Bonus points for hooking `CollectionChanged` of `ObservableCollection` to add  / remove the `PropertyChanged` event on items in the list as they are added and removed.

Comment: Hi bradley,tx for your suggestion.But owing to my novice level in WPF,i m a little lost here.ILiist<MenuCheckBoxData> and strFinalOpts are variables of another class,ie myViewModel while MenuCheckboxData is a different class.I have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented on my ViewModel named "DC_ItemCategory".I am getting a little lost here as to how to read/update strFinalOpts (which is a getter/setter) in DC_ItemCategory when IList<CheckboxData> (a variable of my view model ) registers any change from the control it is associated with in my view.A small example would be of great help.

Comment: Hi grek.I tried to implement your suggestion as well.But as answered to bradley,MenuCheckBoxData is one class while IList<MenuCheckBoxData> and strFinalOpts are properties of another class.So while the control comes to setter  of "Checked" property,how do i update strFinalOpts from there which is a property of another class?

Comment: @JatinderWalia You need to use the at (@) sign in front of the name so other users are notified of your comment-answer.

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach would be to have a some sort of base viewmodel class that provides support for `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent([CallerMemberName]string prop = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T store, T value, [CallerMemberName]string prop = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(store, value))
        {
            store = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(prop);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then implement each viewmodel property with change notifications:

```
public class MenuCheckboxData : BaseViewModel
{
    private int _Id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Id, value); }
    }

    private string _Label;
    public string Label
    {
        get { return _Label; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Label, value); }
    }

    private bool _Checked;
    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return _Checked; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Checked, value); }
    }
}
```

For items collections where the actual items are not static, use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `IList<T>`. Subscribe to `CollectionChanged` in order to manage the `MenuCheckboxData.PropertyChanged` event subscriptions for each item. Whenever a `MenuCheckboxData.PropertyChanged` event is raised for property `Checked`, re-compute the string with IDs.

```
public class Container : BaseViewModel
{
    public Container()
    {
        _MenuOptions = new ObservableCollection<MenuCheckboxData>();
        _MenuOptions.CollectionChanged += MenuOptions_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void MenuOptions_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= MenuCheckboxData_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += MenuCheckboxData_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    void MenuCheckboxData_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Checked")
        {
            // re-evaluate joined id list
            StrFinalOpts = string.Join(",", MenuOptions.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Id.ToString()));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuCheckboxData> _MenuOptions;
    public ObservableCollection<MenuCheckboxData> MenuOptions
    {
        get { return _MenuOptions; }
    }


    private string _StrFinalOpts = "";
    public string StrFinalOpts
    {
        get { return _StrFinalOpts; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _StrFinalOpts, value); }
    }
}
```